# Why am I not able to view my files on Windows, once it was copied from Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, windows, filesystem, malware

I copied a .PDF file from an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system to a flashdrive. No hurdles were found then. After a while, I tried viewing the contents of the flashdrive on a Windows 7 system. But, the its contents were shown inside a shortcut inside the drive (as if it were a virus). So, now I'm not sure if there's a problem with the file-system of if the Ubuntu system had viruses.

Please help !! I'm having trouble printing my .PDF files (printer is attached to the Windows system)

Comment: add the output of `ls -lsa` of the flash drive to your question

Comment: The probability of Ubuntu having a virus is essentially zero.

Comment: Okay Android dev, but, my system could have a vius which is detectable in Windows, but not in Ubuntu which could have been activated when I inserted the flash drive into the Windows system. Could it ?

Comment: Yaron, I didn't get what you just said. I'm not so a technical guy.